# How do I know that a parameter uses ref or params modifier?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

In Mono.Cecil, the [`ParameterDefinition`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/ParameterDefinition.cs) of an [`out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Ee332485(v=VS.100).aspx) parameter has its property `IsOut` set to `true`.

What about [`ref`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/14akc2c7(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w5zay9db(v=vs.100).aspx)? How do I determine, from a `ParameterDefinition`, that one of those modifiers were used for a method parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `ParameterDefinition` doesn't contain `IsRef` or `IsParams`, it's easy to determine both from two other properties.

When the parameter contains a `ref` modifier, the value of `ParameterDefinition.ParameterType.IsByReference` is `true`. Otherwise, it is `false`, even if the actual parameter is a reference type.

As for `params`, the `CustomAttributes` collection contains an element corresponding to `System.ParamArrayAttribute`.

The following piece of code illustrates how to determine the four states:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;

...

if (definition.IsOut)
{
    // There is an `out` modifier.
}
else if (definition.ParameterType.IsByReference)
{
    // There is a `ref` modifier.
}
else if (definition.CustomAttributes.Any(attribute => 
    attribute.AttributeType.FullName == typeof(ParamArrayAttribute).FullName))
{
    // There is a `params` modifier.
}
else
{
    // There are no modifiers.
}
```